# Customizing $product->get_title() function

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, export

i'm customizing a popular CSV exporting tool for Woocommerce.
I've got an issue on extracting names for products.
Look at this line of code:

```
 $product->name = get_the_title($product->ID);
```

This returns a string like

```
  Variation #4923 of ProductName
```

I would like to remove "Variation #Number of " from every export that i make.
I do not want to use a regexp.
I thought about modyfing the first line of code in :

```
$temp = new WC_Product($product->ID);
$product->name = $temp->get_title();
```

so that i could use get_title() which is a native call of Woocommerce.
How can i customize the get_title() function, then?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In WooCommerce, the product variants are children of the actual product. So perhaps just check if the $product_id you're on is a child, and if so get the title of the parent.

Untested code:

```
// Check if product has parent
if($product->post_parent){
    $parents = get_post_ancestors( $product->ID );

    /* Get the top Level page->ID count base 1, array base 0 so -1 */ 
    $parentId = ($parents) ? $parents[count($parents)-1]: $product->ID;

    $product->name = get_the_title($parentId);
}else{
    $product->name = get_the_title($product->ID);
}
```